# vcf tools Error: Require Genotypes in VCF file in order to output Fst statistics

Tags: gatk, vcftools

I want to calculate Fst by vcf tools and GATK. 
I did this steps:

1. for creating gvcf:

`gatk HaplotypeCaller -R ref.scf.fasta -I input.bam -ERC GVCF -O out.g.vcf`

2. for combine:

`gatk CombineGVCFs -R ref.scf.fasta --variant 1.g.vcf --variant 2.g.vcf --variant 3.g.vcf --variant 4.g.vcf --variant 5.g.vcf --variant 6.g.vcf --variant 7.g.vcf --variant 8.g.vcf -O outt.vcf`

3. for genotype:

`gatk GenotypeGVCFs -R ref.scf.fasta --variant outt -O outt.vcflist`

4. for Fst:

`vcftools --vcf outt.vcflist --weir-fst-pop 1.txt --weir-fst-pop 2.txt --out 1_vs_2`

There was no error till step 3 and successfully done. But, I got error in step 4:

```
Error: Require Genotypes in VCF file in order to output Fst statistics.
```

I used the last version (**GATK/4.1.3.0-Java-1.8**) and the last version of vcf tools (**VCFtools/0.1.16**), but I still have the same error!

Would you please advise me?

Best,
Razi